# ЧПУ ссылки с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php, чпу

Здравствуйте. Есть такой url адрес

```
http://домен/index.php?table=datapages&pages=news
```

хочу с помощью .htaccess получить такое

```
http://домен/index/datapages/news
```

В интернете прочитал много статей про это, но ничего не получается. Из последней статьи вроде из этого

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?table=$1&pages=$2
```

должен получится, но ничего не изменяется, помогите, если сможете.

Comment: надеюсь вопрос не про то, что на самом сайте тоже ссылки должны волшебным образом поменяться? ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /index.php?table=$1&pages=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Так тоже не работает.

Comment: Так - [всё прекрасно работает](http://klopp.net.ru/index/datapages/news), ищите ошибки в другом месте (см. RewriteLog и RewriteLogLevel)

Comment: 100% должно сработать

Answer (score 0):

А если так попробовать (общий вид):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^favicon\.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: И так тоже не работает.

Comment: mod_rewrite работает? В файле httpd.conf раскомментированая строка с LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: да работает